# Get a css parameter without creating an element

Tags: javascript, css

I dispose of the following class :

```
.specialCell {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I would like to use this value as a property in JS, eg

```
var specialCellLeftPadding = getCssValue('.specialCell', 'padding-left');
```

The only way I can think of would be to create an element with the wanted class and get the seeked attribute value :

```
var tmpElt = document.createElement('div');
tmpElt.className = 'specialCell';
document.body.appendChild(tmpElt);
var specialCellLeftPadding = getComputedProperties(tmpElt).getPropertyValue('padding-left');
document.body.removeChild(tmpElt);
```

Is it possible to achieve the same purpose without creating and adding an new element to the dom ? (assuming no element with this class exists).

Comment: @Patrick indeed, didn't see this question

Comment: One issue that I see with the approach is that whatever style you'll get will be missing the element's context that may be essential to determine the CSS parameter. For example, you could have this in your CSS: `.specialCell { padding-left:10px; }` and `table#myTable .specialCell { padding-left:30px; }`. Which one should be returned for `getCssValue('.specialCell', 'padding-left')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can query CSS information directly from stylesheets using the [CSSOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model). E.g.,

```js
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = stylesheet.cssRules[0].style.paddingLeft;
```

```css
.test { padding-left: 12px; }
```

```html
Padding left: <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Is this cross-browser ? The mdn page is quite evasive on the subject.

Comment: Do you need to know the exact position of the rule in the CSS file? or would it be possible to access it as an index (e.g.: `stylesheet.cssRules[".test"].style.paddingLeft;`)?

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from the example of [dystroy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431617/116249), you can get a css value using the document.styleSheets property

Using the css

```
.specialCell {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

and

```
function getCssProperty(cssclass, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
        var cssRules = styleSheet.rules ||  // chrome, IE
                       styleSheet.cssRules; // firefox
        for (var ir = cssRules.length; ir-- > 0;) {
            var rule = cssRules[ir];
            if (rule.selectorText == "." + cssclass) {
                return rule.style.getPropertyValue(property);

            }
        }
    }
}

var prop = getCssProperty('specialCell', 'padding-left');
console.info(prop);
```

this example will  print `10px` in the console